# Batch file : skipping folders starting with _ in FOR loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, token, delimiter

I would like to exclude all profiles starting with **_** without having to list each profile in an exclusion text file.

Is it possible to do this ?

```
@echo off
set Target=D:\backup

        for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /a:d-h /b "%SystemDrive%\Users\*"') do if exist "%Target%\%%~nXI\" (

    ........

)

pause
exit
```

Thank you very much in advance for helping !

Comment: Use the __FOR__ command line `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A:D-H /B "%HomeDrive%\Users\*" 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /L /V "_"') do if exist "%Target%\%%I\" (` which excludes the user profile directories starting with an underscore on drive with the user profiles (home directories). Note: `%SystemDrive%` and `%HomeDrive%` expand usually to same string, but `%HomeDrive%` is the correct variable for this task.

Comment: There is absolutely no guarantee that all local profiles will be found on `%systemdrive%` or `%homedrive%`, nevermind within a directory named `Users`. Additionally, there is no guarantee that the name of the directory holding the profile, matches that of the users profile name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code example provides a methodology for retrieving the profile names you require, *(those which are not  a special account and whose names do not begin with an underscore)*, together with their current profile paths.

```batch-file
@For /F "Skip=1Tokens=1,2" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Where^
 "LocalAccount='True' And Not Name Like '[_]%%'" Get Name^,SID 2^>Nul'
)Do @For /F %%I In ("%%H")Do @For /F "Tokens=2Delims==" %%J In ('
 %__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_UserProfile Where^
 "SID='%%I' And Special!='True'" Get LocalPath /Value 2^>Nul'
)Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%K In ("%%J")Do @Echo User name:"%%G",Profile path:"%%K"
@Pause
```

Whilst the above does not directly help you with your task, it could very simply be adapted, to do so. *(It even affords you the opportunity to use `%%K` too, should you be copying/moving objects between the profile path and the target directory.)*:

```batch-file
@Set "Target=D:\backup"
@For /F "Skip=1Tokens=1,2" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Where^
 "LocalAccount='True' And Not Name Like '[_]%%'" Get Name^,SID 2^>Nul'
)Do @For /F %%I In ("%%H")Do @For /F "Tokens=2Delims==" %%J In ('
 %__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_UserProfile Where^
 "SID='%%I' And Special!='True'" Get LocalPath /Value 2^>Nul'
)Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%K In ("%%J")Do @If Exist "%Target%\%%G\" (
    Rem …your code here
)
@Pause
```

---

If there's a possibility that you have user names containing spaces, the answer becomes a little more involved. It could be done more simply if you were definitely running this on systems which weren't Windows 7, but this should work regardless of which supported OS you're using.

```batch-file
@Set "Target=D:\backup"
@For /F Tokens^=4Delims^=^" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount^
 Where "LocalAccount='TRUE' And Not Name Like '[_]%%'" Assoc:List^
 /ResultRole:SID 2^>NUL')Do @For /F Tokens^=1* %%H In (
 '%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Where "Name='%%G'" Get SID^
 /Value 2^>NUL^|%__AppDir__%find.exe "="')Do @For %%I In (%%H
)Do @For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%J In ( 
 '%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_UserProfile Where^
 "SID='%%I' And Special!='TRUE' And LocalPath Is Not Null" Get LocalPath /Value^
 2^>NUL^|%__AppDir__%find.exe "="')Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%L In ("%%K"
)Do @If Exist "%Target%\%%G\" (
    Rem …your code here
)
@Pause
```

*In this example, your user profile path will be assigned to `%%~L`, (as opposed to `%%K`, in the previous example.).*