# Issues when getting a list of user profiles using WMIC

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, wmic

I was using the following batch command to retrieve all local user profiles (including domain users too) :

```
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /a:d-h /b "%SystemDrive%\Users\*" 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /i /l /x /v /g:"%bin%\exclude_users.txt"') do (
```

The problem is that this command has its limits: it doesn't really check if the users in question do actually have an account.

The user Compo provided me a methodology for retrieving the profile names, using WMIC.

So I ended up writing the following command:

```
@For /F "tokens=* skip=1" %%I In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Get Name ^|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /i /l /x /v /g:"%bin%\exclude_users.txt"') do (
```

The problem is: it ignores my exclusion file (which contains one user per line) and it ends up  a profile without any name.

Any idea How I can solve these issues ?

Comment: Well, I think of two issues: 1. `wmic` returns Unicode text, which `findstr` may have trouble with; 2. `wmic` often appends spaces, which disturb `findstr /X`. Using `wmic ... /VALUE` avoids the latter, but of course the output format is different then, which you need to account for...

Comment: If the exclusion list is rather short you might try this: `wmic UserAccount where "Name!='UsrExcl1' and Name!='UsrExcl2' and ..." get Name`?

Comment: I thought you were only trying to exclude users with names beginning with an underscore, and [I have already answered that question for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61411509), and that also excluded the special accounts like Administrator etc. too!

Comment: Yes but it turns out that I have many other users (more than 30) with names don't begin with an underscore. So, no way to use wmic with an exclusion list ?

Comment: Complete the code with `echo "%%~I")`. This shows you the output of `"%%~I"`. You need to trim the `wmic` output before piping it to `findstr`.

Comment: The output is : "User1 "User2 "User "   (blank)

Comment: @Cospuser, just because a task changes post question, it doesn't invalidate answers received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "bin=%~dp0"

for /f "tokens=* skip=1" %%I in ('
    %__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount where Disabled^="FALSE" get Name ^|
    %__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell -noprofile -command "$input.trim()" ^|
    %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /i /l /x /v /g:"%bin%\exclude_users.txt"
') do echo "%%~I"
```

The `wmic` output is piped to `powershell` to be trimmed and then piped to `findstr`.

The `wmic` command will exclude disabled accounts by use of the `where` clause.

Change the setting of `bin` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution which still uses WMIC, and your exclusion list, then the following should do as you require.

```batch-file
@For /F Tokens^=4Delims^=^" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Where "LocalAccount='TRUE'" Assoc:List /ResultRole:Name 2^>NUL')Do @Echo %%G|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /VXLIG:"%~dp0exclude_users.txt"
```

You can split that over multiple lines for easier reading too:

```batch-file
@For /F Tokens^=4Delims^=^" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount^
 Where "LocalAccount='TRUE'" Assoc:List /ResultRole:Name 2^>NUL'
)Do @Echo %%G|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /VXLIG:"%~dp0exclude_users.txt"
```