# Exclude some outputs from WMIC query

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic, findstr

I'm getting the list of Windows users and their local path, through wmic (thanks Compo).

I would like some user names to be excluded from the output in this wmic command :

```
@For /F "Skip=1Tokens=1,2" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Where^
 "LocalAccount='True' And Not Name Like '[_]%%'" Get Name^,SID 2^>Nul'
)Do @For /F %%I In ("%%H")Do @For /F "Tokens=2Delims==" %%J In ('
 %__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_UserProfile Where^
 "SID='%%I' And Special!='True'" Get LocalPath /Value 2^>Nul'
)Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%K In ("%%J")Do @Echo User name:"%%G",Profile path:"%%K"
```

I'm not sure how I can add this exclusion file :

```
%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /V /X / L/ /I G:"usernames.txt"
```

Can you help me please ?

Thank you

Comment: `)Do` must be `) Do` (two places), then append `| %__AppDir_...` and fix the switches... `/V /X /L /I /G:`

Comment: @Magoo, FYI, although it may not technically be correct, `)Do` need not be `) Do`, _in the same way as `)Else` need not be `) Else`_!

Comment: How many usernames are you wanting to exclude? This code already excludes all of those which begin with an underscore. So, let's say you have three, `Peter`, `Kalinda`, and `Dimitri`; you could change `And Not Name Like '[_]%%'` to `And Name!='Dimitri' And Name!='Kalinda' And Name!='Peter'`.

Comment: BTW, for any future readers, the OP's code was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61411509), and was not a response to them. A. Joson, despite thanking me in the question, I'm assuming that you didn't upvote my original efforts, as I have received none for almost ten months, is there a particular reason why?

Comment: My recommendation is to ditch batch/WMIC/awkward output and string parsing and switch to PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to exclude names from the output, the general rule for efficiency, is to filter your commands as soon as possible in your code.

For this reason, the most efficient method would be to make the individual exclusions within the `Where` clause. I provided an example of how to do that in my comment, e.g. change the current exclusion, of names beginning with an underscore, (`And Not Name Like '[_]%%'`), to `And Name!='Dimitri' And Name!='Kalinda' And Name!='Peter'`.

If you have a list of exclusions one per line in a file, and there are too many to transfer into the `Where` clause, then you should perform that filtering in the `Do` portion of that initial `For` loop. You could at that point use `findstr.exe` with the options you chose, *(just fixed)*.

As the code you chose from my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61411509) was not the robust one, which caters for user names with spaces/problematic characters, I'd suggest you change to that too.

For that reason, this would be my suggested answer, *(excluding names within `usernames.txt` using `findstr.exe`)*:

```sh
@For /F Tokens^=4Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 UserAccount Where "LocalAccount='TRUE'" Assoc:List /ResultRole:SID 2^>NUL'
)Do @Set /P "=%%G"<NUL|%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /XVLIG:"usernames.txt"^
 >NUL&&(For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
     UserAccount Where "Name='%%G'" Get SID /Value 2^>NUL
     ^|%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "="')Do @For %%J In (%%I
    )Do @For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%K In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
     Path Win32_UserProfile Where (SID^="%%J" And Special!^="TRUE" And LocalPath
     Is Not Null^) Get LocalPath /Value 2^>NUL^|%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe
     "="')Do @For /F Tokens^=* %%M In ("%%L"
     )Do @Echo UserName:"%%G", UserProfile:"%%M")
```