# Batch Treat special characters as input errors

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, input, cmd

I want all non-numeric characters to be considered as input error. Alphabetic characters are well considered but not certain special characters like colons (and others ones).

Any idea how to achieve this ?

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a UserProfileNo=0

FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('dir /a:d /b "%SystemDrive%\Users\"') do (

    set "UserProfileName=%%~I"
    set /a UserProfileNo+=1
    set "UserProfileName[!UserProfileNo!]=!UserProfileName!"

)

FOR /L %%k IN (1, 1, %UserProfileNo%) DO echo  %%~k !UserProfileName[%%~k]!
    set /p choice=Enter a Profile Number: 

FOR %%f IN (%choice%) DO if "!UserProfileName[%%~f]!" == "" (
    echo Error in the input
    goto end
    )

echo NO Error in the input

:end

pause

exit
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use findstr regex to restrict characters:

```bat
@Echo off
call :input rv[1] 0123456789 "enter a number"
call :input rv[2] a-zA-Z "enter a alphanumerical string"
call :input rv[3] "a-zA-Z " "enter an alpha sentence"
set rv[
Goto :Eof

:input [ReturnVar] [CharacterString] [prompt]
 Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
:retry
 Set "input="
 Set /P "input=%~3: "
 If  "!input!" == "" Goto :retry
 Echo("!input!"| %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /RXC:"[\"][%~2]*[\"]" >nul || Goto :retry
 Endlocal & Set "%~1=%input%"
 Exit /B 0
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, your code doesn't exclude the characters `!` and `;`

Comment: @A.Joson those two issues are easily fixed.

Comment: @[A.Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10696571/a-joson) code amended to remove those characters via substring modification. Findstr alternative added to answer

Comment: Sadly your last code doesn't exclude the characters `^` and `&`

Answer (score 0):

I'd offer an expansion of [the code I've provided for you before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66431207), for performing this task.

The following code will list all standard local users and allow you to choose one from the list, by its numerical index. Only valid index numbers, (no other normal characters), will be accepted, *including `!`, `"`, `%`, `^`, `&`, `)`, `=`, `|`, `<`, and `>`*

Using this method, it does not limit output only to user profiles located in the hardcoded path `%SystemDrive%\Users`, nor does it depend upon the directory name for the profile matching the account holder's name, *(if a user changes their account name, their profile directory is not renamed to reflect that change)*.

```
@Echo Off&SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=0"&For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set User[) 2>NUL"')Do Set "%%G="
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe OS Call /?
 ^| %__AppDir__%find.exe "=="') Do Set "#=%%G"
For /F Tokens^=4Delims^=^" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Where
 "LocalAccount='TRUE'" Assoc:List /ResultRole:SID 2^>NUL'
)Do For /F Tokens^=1* %%H In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Where
 "Name='%%G'" Get SID /Value 2^>NUL^|%__AppDir__%find.exe "="'
)Do For %%I In (%%H)Do For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%J In ( 
 '%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_UserProfile Where
 "SID='%%I' And Special!='TRUE' And LocalPath Is Not Null" Get LocalPath /Value
 2^>NUL^|%__AppDir__%find.exe "="')Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%L In ("%%K")Do (
    Set /A i+=1&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion&Echo !i!.%#:~-1%%%G
    For %%M In (!i!)Do EndLocal&Set "User[%%M]Name=%%G"&Set "User[%%M]Path=%%L")
If Not Defined User[1]Name (Echo No standard users found, Press a key to end.
    GoTo :EOF)

:Pick
Echo(&Set "#="
Set /P "#=Enter the number for your chosen Account Name>"
Set "#=%#:"=%"
(Set User[)|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /BL "User[%#%]Name=">NUL||GoTo Pick
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion&For /F UseBackTokens^=1^,3Delims^=^" %%G In (
    '"!User[%#%]Name!" "!User[%#%]Path!"')Do (EndLocal&Set "User[Name]=%%G"
    Set "User[Profile]=%%H"&Set "#=")
(For /L %%G In (1,1,%i%)Do For %%H In (Name Path)Do Set User[%%G]%%H=)&Set "i="
Echo(&Echo You Selected %User[Name]% - [profile location is %User[Profile]%]
%__AppDir__%timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak>NUL
```

The last two lines are for demonstration purposes only, you would replace those with your own code, only after testing. Their inclusion was to demonstrate that a valid input entry will create two new local variables, `%User[Name]%`, *(the `%UserName%` for the input index number)*, and `%User[Profile]%`, *(the `%UserProfile%` for the input index number)*.

---

***Please note:** The code above should only be run and tested exactly as it exists above, with no omissions, additions, or modifications. If it fails to work as intended, I will accept changing all instances of `%__AppDir__%` with `%SystemRoot%\System32\`, before asking for support.*